# Why does JS processing and paint occur at the end of each frame?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

My webpage is basically a single canvas which I'm updating with WebGL. I'm trying to get a smooth horizontal animation (basically, like a crawl you would see on TV). My frames are all under 16.6 ms, but the animation still has small stutters. Looking at the Timeline in DevTools, it appears all the work (JS and paint) is occurring at the end of the frame. I'm wonder if this is causing the stutter. I also don't understand why this work does not occur earlier in the first 10 ms of each frame.

My render loop looks like this:

```
    function animate(now) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        crawl.position.x -= STEP_SIZE;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        bufferCopy();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the render implementation is the responsible for that. Did you check the documentation? Where you have the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)

Comment: I'm inclined to think the devtools visualizes frame boundaries incorrectly.

Comment: @Teocci I take a look tho it might be difficult for me to decipher.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could be that devtools simply measures the frame as beginning with the last paint and counting forward.

Comment: What is puzzling me is, looking at the timeline, I would think the animation would be smooth since I'm adding only about 6 ms of work to each frame.

Comment: @Jonas, that's what I think too. As for the stutter, look at the green GPU bars: some frames are filled 100% which indicates GPU is a bottleneck. I'm not an expert on debugging paint issues but IIRC some official devtools tutorial on the topic tells something about minimizing the paint region.

Comment: I think the JS processing start just ahead the actual frame, so compositing (including webgl) have a full 'vsync' frame to proceed.